Proxy contract : Errore "could not decode result data" durante l'interazione con il contratto tramite proxy in Hardhat
I'm trying to implement and test a proxy pattern for my smart contracts using Hardhat and Ethers.js. However, I'm encountering an issue when I attempt to call the functions of the implementation contract through the proxy. Below are the details of my setup and the error I'm receiving.
Issue
During deployment, the value is set successfully through the proxy, but when I try to retrieve it, I receive the following error:

An error occurred during the deployment process: Error: could not
decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "getValue",
"signature": "getValue()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.13.2)

Storage contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 pragma solidity ^0.8.24;
    contract StorageTest {
        uint256 public value; // Variabile di stato per memorizzare un valore
        address[50] private ______gap; // Spazio riservato per aggiungere variabili di stato future
    }

Proxy contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract ProxyTest {
    address private implementation;

    constructor(address _implementation) {
        implementation = _implementation;
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        address impl = implementation;
        require(impl != address(0), "Implementation contract required");

        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40) // Carica il puntatore della memoria libera
            calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize()) // Copia i dati della chiamata nella memoria
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), impl, ptr, calldatasize(), 0, 0) // Esegue delegatecall
            let size := returndatasize() // Ottieni la dimensione dei dati restituiti
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size) // Copia i dati restituiti nella memoria

            switch result
            case 0 {
                revert(ptr, size) // Se il risultato è 0, esegui revert
            }
            default {
                return(ptr, size) // Restituisci i dati se la chiamata è andata a buon fine
            }
        }
    }
}

Implementation contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "../storage/StorageTest.sol";
contract ImplementationTest is StorageTest {
    // Evento per tracciare quando viene impostato un nuovo valore
    event ValueSet(uint256 value);

    // Imposta il valore nella memoria
    function setValue(uint256 _value) public {
        value = _value;
        emit ValueSet(value); // Emissione dell'evento dopo aver impostato il valore
    }

    // Ottieni il valore dalla memoria
    function getValue() public view returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }
}

config
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'); 
require('dotenv').config();
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  solidity: {
    version: '0.8.24', 
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
  }

deployement
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  try {
    console.log("Starting the deployment process...");

    // Ottieni il signer (account del deployer)
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

    // Ottieni il bilancio dell'account usando il provider
    const balance = await deployer.provider.getBalance(deployer.address);
    console.log("Account balance:", ethers.formatEther(balance), "ETH");

    // Deploy del contratto di storage
    console.log("Deploying the Storage contract...");
    const Storage = await ethers.getContractFactory("StorageTest");
    const storage = await Storage.deploy();
    await storage.waitForDeployment(); // Usa waitForDeployment() per assicurarti che il contratto sia stato effettivamente deployato
    const storageAddress = await storage.getAddress(); // Ottieni l'indirizzo del contratto deployato
    console.log("Storage contract deployed to:", storageAddress);

    // Deploy del contratto di implementazione
    console.log("Deploying the Implementation contract...");
    const Implementation = await ethers.getContractFactory("ImplementationTest");
    const implementation = await Implementation.deploy();
    await implementation.waitForDeployment(); // Usa waitForDeployment() per assicurarti che il contratto sia stato effettivamente deployato
    const implementationAddress = await implementation.getAddress();
    console.log("Implementation contract deployed to:", implementationAddress);

    // Deploy del contratto proxy
    console.log("Deploying the Proxy contract...");
    const Proxy = await ethers.getContractFactory("ProxyTest");
    const proxy = await Proxy.deploy(implementationAddress);
    await proxy.waitForDeployment(); // Usa waitForDeployment() per assicurarti che il contratto sia stato effettivamente deployato
    const proxyAddress = await proxy.getAddress();
    console.log("Proxy contract deployed to:", proxyAddress);

    // Interagisci con il contratto tramite il proxy
    console.log("Attaching the implementation contract to the proxy...");
    const implementationWithProxy = await ethers.getContractAt("ImplementationTest", proxyAddress);

    // Imposta un valore tramite il proxy
    const newValue = 42;
    console.log(`Setting the value ${newValue} through the proxy...`);
    const tx = await implementationWithProxy.setValue(newValue);
    console.log("Transaction hash:", tx.hash);
    await tx.wait(); // Attendi che la transazione venga minata
    console.log("Value has been set.");

    // Ottieni il valore tramite il proxy
    console.log("Retrieving the value through the proxy...");
    const value = await implementationWithProxy.getValue();
    console.log("Value from proxy:", value.toString());

    console.log("Deployment process completed successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred during the deployment process:", error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  }
}

main();

It seems there's an issue with interpreting the result of the getValue function call through the proxy. I have checked my delegatecall assembly code, and everything seems fine.
What I've Tried
Verified that the contract addresses are correct.
Used ethers.getContractAt to interact with the contract through the proxy.
Ensured the proxy receives and delegates calls to the implementation contract.
Question
Does anyone know why the result of the getValue() function is not being decoded correctly when called through the proxy? Is there something I'm missing in my delegation pattern, or is there a known issue with Ethers.js in this setup?
Thanks in advance for any help!
